# IE8 Catch enter keypress in form submit

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I've got this simple form:

```
<form>
    <input id="txt" type="text">
    <input id="sb" type="submit">
</form>
```

When the form is submitted I want to know if it was submitted by pressing `enter`.  How can I get this information?

I tried this with jquery:

```
$("#txt").keyup(function(event){if(event.keyCode==13)...});
```

This works except in IE8. In IE8 the form is submitted without triggering the `keyup` function.  Unfortunately, I have to make this work in IE8.

Comment: try changing to keydown.

Comment: Also, make sure the site is not running in compatibility mode.

Comment: Wow, keydown does the trick.

Comment: @ry4nolson: Rewrite this an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) to capture the enter key *before* the form is submitted.

```
$("#txt").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6fKez/

Comment: Thanks, but not quite.  With `preventDefault` my form is not submitted.  And the fiddle doesn't even load in my IE but that is fiddle's fault I suppose.

But the `keydown` does the trick.

Comment: @MichaelLemke You can remove the `.preventDefault`, I just put it in there for the demo since you didn't post the rest of your code.